# How to use multiple arrays in one component using map (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

what I have is a box(component) with props of header and description. I want to use this component with arrays to put in the props using map. So I can create multiple boxes in on tag.

I did as below, but of course did not work. I want to use .map to solve this. Can you please help?

```
  import Item from './component/Item.js';

function App() {
  const [words,setWords] = useState(['description 1', 'description 2']);
  const [titles,setTitles] = useState(['Fried Chicken', 'Chocolatte']);

  return   (<Item text={words.map} header={titles.map}) />
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty odd to have items in separate states that contain linked values - better to have a single state array instead, then all you have to do is `.map` over it, which is trivial.

```
function App() {
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState([
    { header: 'Fried Chicken', description: 'description 1' },
    { header: 'Chocolate', description: 'description 2' },
  ]);
  return itemData.map(({ header, description }) => <Item header={header} text={description} />);
}
```

If you don't ever change the `itemData`, then you can remove the state part entirely and use a static array instead, to make things a bit simpler.